# Which is the proper way to save XML value node that contains &amp;#38 into the database?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, decode, encode

Today someone has sent an XML to my asp.net 4.8 backend app, like this one:

```
<person>
   <name>example1 &amp;#38 example2</name>
</person>
```

The server app reads the node value and saves it in an sql db column dbo.Person.Name without any decoding. first dubt: is it bad ? how should be stored ? Should be decoded first.

Anyway assuming the value will be saved as is, soon or later the client side part of the application will request data from the server and this string will be sent to the client and shown correctly, since it is an html encoded string.

The issue I am dealing with is a Validation Exception thrown when the client gives back this data in a post request to the server.

The easy why should be to replace/escape the "&#38" contained in the post's body.

Is it the best way to deal with ? How data should be transfer beetween server and client ?

Comment: If I had a column called "dbo.Person.Name" I wouldn't expect that to contain any XML. It should just contain the raw name of the person. Why are you wanting to store XML there?

Comment: At first, I thought, store it as is.  &amp;#38; is the hex code for "&", but since the character "&" identifies a character entity, it's properly escaped for an XML (not human) parser to read.

Then I realized that you're missing the trailing ";" semi-colon, and I think you'll have "&38" appear in the browser.  Looks like someone wrote their own XML parser, and escaped "&"  it improperly, which is usually simply "&amp;"

Comment: mason, I am not storing the xml, but only the inner value of the xml "name" node

Comment: If the data that you store in the database isn't intended to be XML, then why would you have it encoded as if it were?

Comment: William Walseth, you had right about the missing character. Anyway it has been saved as &#38 into database... From the client side I have found this function to invoke before post data back to the server and it seems working $("<textarea/>").html(this.name).text() - do u think could be the right solution ?

Comment: yes mason, it is saved as &#38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Today someone has sent an XML"

Get back to them and ask them why they're sending such dirty data and tell them you're not prepared to put such grot in your database.

It looks on the face of it as if `&amp;#38` is a completely botched attempt to escape an ampersand.

Comment: Sir, It is the final answer or is there a way to be prepared ? any advice ? For sure I have understood that the xml is wrong made. So the only way to solve the issue seems to search this pattern and fix it before saving it into the database. Do u agree ?

Comment: @Lluthus Why are you asking us? Why would the only way to be to fix the XML? Why don't you simply contact whoever sent the bad data and have them fix it?

Comment: I absolutely DON'T agree. If someone sends you a sack of flour and it's full of weevils, you don't sift through it to remove the weevils, you send it back, complain to the supplier, and/or find another supplier. You've been sent junk; if they get details like this wrong, then you can't trust them as a supplier of data and there is no way you should put this stuff in your precious database.